# Need help about grails domain class design

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I need to create grails domain class like this(see image),but I don't know how to do. Can someone please give me the solution,please?

Image : http://www.uppicweb.com/x/i/ib/6demo.jpg

Answer (score 2):

From the picture, you don't need a single domain class.  You need one for every box in your image.  So you would have a 'Customer' domain object, 'ProductComment', 'Product', etc, and you would relate them via the techniques discussed in chapter 5 of the Grails documentaiton.

There should be plenty of information on the interwebs about this, you can start here:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. You need to create a domain class for each box in your picture.
That means:

- Customer
- Cart
- Product
- Product_comment
- Product_category
- Bill
- Bill_item

Take a look on [GORM documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html).

Then you can [create controllers with scaffolding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/16.%20Scaffolding.html) and start to play.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if there is requirement that name of your id should be product_id, cart_id etc then you have to look at the documentation how to do that. Otherwise, in grails by default the id field name is id only.